# Guess the number. Maximizing expected winnings?

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

A man in a trench coat approaches you and pulls an envelope from his pocket. He tells you that it contains a sum of money in bills, anywhere from 1 dollar up to 1,000 dollars. He says that if you can guess the exact amount, you can keep the money. After each of your guesses he will tell you if your guess is too high, or too low. But! You only get nine tries. What should your first guess be to maximize your expected winnings?

Comment: Start with $512$. If your guess is higher, then decrease by $256$. If lower, increase by $256$. Continue in the same manner, this time with $128$, then with $64$, then with $32$, then with $16$, then with $8$, then with $4$, then with $2$, then with $1$. After at most $9$ guesses, you'll reach the exact amount.

Comment: Just to make it completely accurate, your initial value can be anywhere between $489$ and $512$.

Comment: May be three zones faster with pivots 333 and 667. If < 333 , regula falsi by 333/2. Next 667 same process.

Comment: @barakmanos I think you've used 10 guesses.

Comment: Um,  Don't you need 10 guesses for certainty?  With 9 guesses you are slightly higher than 50% I think.  To literally maximize expected return I'd say guess high, i.e. start at 512

Comment: We can only determine 512 possible values with certainty in 9 guesses.  So we can't guess with certainty.  So if we are effiecient we have a 488/1000 probability of losing.  To maximize our expected returns we guess high.  If the dollar amount is 1-488 we lose.  If 489-1000 we win.  He start the guess and 488 + 256.

Comment: @Pedro What happens if I guessed right?

Comment: Ugh this is even worse than I thought. You need 11 guesses to guess with certainty.  10 to know with certainty and the 11th to state it.  For example if there were 4 = 2^2 options.  The first guess will resolve it to two options.  The second guess is one of those options, after which you will know the answer but to *state* the answer is a third guess.

Comment: I gave an "up" vote to the first 2 comments by barak manos for giving the right idea , provoking someone to give a right answer even though the conclusion is wrong.

Comment: Presumably the man wants to minimize your expected winnings, as it's zero-sum.  What is *his* optimal strategy?

Comment: When I said it was worse than I thought it wasn't that bad.  In a guess you have three not to information options although one is very narrow: high low or exact.  In k guesses you can cover $2^k - 1$ options.  (via induction.  The k+1 guess can give you a "lower" to cover $2^k-1$ option or a higher for $2^k -1$ or an "exact" for 1 option.  That's 2^{k+1}-1 option.)

Comment: @mjqxxxx  Presumably to only provide a single dollar.  If you win you don't get much.  And most players to maximize will not have a strategy that covers one  Or actually he could simply lie when he tells you you guessed high or low.

Answer (score 2):

My old answer is the right idea but the wrong answer.

New strategy.  If it is 489 or below we will not guess it.  If it is 490 or above, we will.

For our ninth guess we want to have only one possible guess.  If the amount is  490 or above it will be the correct guess.  Otherwise we have resigned to losing.

For our eight guess we will have 3 possible guesses.  We will guess the middle amount.  Either it is right.  It is high.  Or it is lower.  If it is right we are done.  If it isn't there are 1 possible guess remaining.  That will be our 9th guess.

For our 7th guess we will have 7 possiblie guesses.  We will guess the middle.  If we are wrong the 3 remaining possibilities will form our 8th guess.

And so one.

For our 6th guess we guess the middle of 15.  Our 5th the middle of 31.  Our 4th, the middle of 63.  Our 3rd, the middl of 127.  Our second, the middle of 255.  Our first the middle of 511.

Our first guess will be 746.  If the amount is anywhere between 490 and 1000 we will guess it by 9 guesses.  Otherwise we won't.

Our expected return is $511/1000*746 = \$381$.

==== old answer ====

Okay, you can't guess with certainty.  9 guesses will divide the information into 512 cases so you will only have about a 1 in 2 chance of making it.

Since the puzzle is to *maximize* expected return, we should guess so that if we make it we will win the highest amount of money.  So if we don't make it we should fail to guess the lowest amount.  So we should decide as we have a 1-2 (roughly) chance of losing, we should make it so that we lose only if there is less than 500 dollars and we will win if there is more.  Thus our expected return will be about 375 dollars.

So we should first guess should be \$744 ($1000 - 2^8$).  If we guess low we up the guess by \$256 ($2^8$) and if we guess high we lower by \$256.  Each guess we hone in by half.  If the amount is between \$489 and \$1000, we will guess it.  If it isn't we won't.  So our expected return is $512/1000 * (1000 + 489)/2 = \$381$

Comment: This answer assumes a uniform distribution of the sought for number - yet another ambiguity in the question. Modulo that assumption I think your answer is correct. +1.

Comment: Yes, my answer does assume that.  I don't think it's meaningful to make any expectation other wise.

Comment: I suppose if the money is uniformly distributed will want our choices to center at 500. We can, more or less, have our guesses be successful with 511/1000.   To maximize we have to know how they are distributed.

Comment: New thought.  If we use my strategy and if as response we get both "higher" and "lower" we know we have selected the correct range.  If the actual amount is outside the range the responses are uniform.  If we get n uniform responses maybe we can conclude likelihood that the amount is out of range and adjust.  Thinking off the top of my head.  Guess 500 if "low" then 500-128 if "low" again try 500-256 under the assumption it was out of the 256-750 to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

A binary tree of depth $N$ can have up to 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N 2^k = 2^{N+1} - 1
$$
nodes. Here we have $N = 9$ and thus can store up to $1023$
values.

So $9$ questions are enough to drill down to any dollar value between $1$ and $1000$. We have a little wiggle room , but we take simply $512$.

Comment: Are you sure? With $N=1$ guess you can't identify a number between 1 and 3. You may need two.

Comment: I would ask $2$ and get the answer lower, higher or whatever reaction, when $2$ was right.

Comment: If the number isn't $2$ then you do know what it is but you may need another "guess" to tell the man in the trench coat. There's some ambiguity in the question.

Comment: Ok, What number between $1$ and $3$ I am thinking of?

Comment: 2^9 = 512 so you can only determine with certainty 1 of 512 possible outcomes.  1000> 512 so this can't be done with certainty.

Comment: You can use the inner nodes as well.

Comment: You are only allowed 9 guesses.  If you are able to say something *after* your ninth guess, that is a 10th guess.  I don't understand the comment about inner nodes.

Comment: I would already know, so another question Is not needed. You assume one would need it to be able to get the microfon and state the end. I had assumed once the knowledge is there it is over. The problem is not well specified, the end condition is unclear.